# Send a message to another application in linux

Tags: c#, linux, cross-platform, sendmessage, cross-application

I want to send a meesage from one application to another.
In windows I would use a DllImprt for PostMessage or SendMessage.

What Can I do in linux?
Is there an option not to use PostMessage or SendMessage in windows?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at D-Bus:
http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus

Not sure it works on Windows, but it's quite popular for Linux applications.